# How to work on React Native project on text editor and view it in Android Studio simultaneously?

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native

My React Native Project Folder is as such:

-- Gifton-Project
--- android
--- ios
--- app 
---- components 
(etc.)

So, when I open this in Android Studio, I only open the "android" folder.

However, my source code (?) that I want to edit is under "app/components", that is outside the "android" folder. As such, when I modify and save my code in a text editor like Atom, the changes aren't reflected on Android Studio when I run it in the emulator.

How may I do this, and especially simply, without having to reload everything?

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Since every `react-native run-android` commands first generates the build and then installed it in the device/emulator, you want be able to view changes since you are running the already generated build from android studio.

Whenever you do changes in JS files, it won't get directly reflected in android studio and the build running from that.

Try running `react-native run-android` and toggle **hot reload** in order to view the changes directly in emulator. As soon as you hit save, changes will be refelected.

You need not to to run project from the android studio separately.

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps:

1) Along with Android Studio and Atom, simultaneously run a terminal window with command `npm start`.

2) After *Loading dependency graph* is done, keep the `metro bundler` running in background.

3) Run the project with Android Studio.

4) Edit your React-Native code in Atom or any other editor.

5) Save your code.

6) Reload in Android Emulator (press `RR` in android)